# Floor function values of $x$

Tags: systems-of-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I found a question where we need to find the number of values satisfying this equation with the constraint that $x \in (0,1000)$

$$\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{5}\right\rfloor=\frac{31x}{30}$$ where $\left\lfloor.\right\rfloor$ represents the floor function of $x$.

Now here its obvious that the right hand side must also give out an integer hence all the multiples of $30$ would work hence giving $30$ solutions between $0$ and $1000$ the result must be in form of $\frac{30k}{31}$ but how do I find such $k$ so as to give the other solution of $x$. Is there any method to solve the equation directly? Any hint would work.

Comment: I would have thought you have shown $x$ must be an integer multiple of $30$.  All these work and there are $\lfloor \frac{1000-1}{30} \rfloor = 33$ of them strictly greater than $0$ and less than $1000$

Comment: $x$ is an integer? Not necessarily, but since the LHS so must be the right, correct?

Comment: @JimmyR. There is no such condition mentioned.

Comment: @Henry How do I prove there is no value of x in the form of $\frac {30k}{31}$ because this would also give the values of integers in the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x=\frac{30k}{31}$ is not an integer

then there is rounding down and $\displaystyle \left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{5}\right\rfloor \lt \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x}{5} = \frac{31x}{30}$

so the only solutions are of the form $x=30k$ for integer $k$

Comment: Since the left side is an integer, then $\dfrac{31x}{30}$ must be an integer. So $30 \mid x$.